# I can not see network drive of one drive

Tags: interface

I'm beginner and I'd like to save on Microsoft's OneDrive but it is not displayed.
Blender can not save in cloud?

Comment: If you're using the common setup of OneDrive it's not a network drive, but a folder on your system from which the files get synchronized to the cloud by the OneDrive app. Blender can save to that folder. It's commonly found in `C:\Users\yourusername` (replace yourusername with your actual user name).

Comment: Hi
Thank you, I found the OneDrive in C:.I did not know where the one drive .